# F#: Why can't I cons an object of type B to a list of type A when B is a subtype of A?

Tags: f#

According to the 3rd example on this site http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233224.aspx, F# lists can contain objects of different types as long as both types derive from the same super-type. However, I can't get the cons (::) operator to add subtypes to a list of the supertype

```
module test

type A() =
    member this.x = 2

type B() =
    inherit A()
    member this.y = 4

let mutable myList : A list = []
myList <- [B()] // Valid
myList <- B()::myList // Invalid: This expression was expected to have type A but here has type B
```

Is there a reason I can't use `::` to append to the list?

Comment: Try `let mutable myList : #A list = []` or `myList <- (upcast B())::myList`.

Comment: @ildjarn Your first suggestion results in a warning: This construct causes code to be less generic than indicated by its type annotations. The type variable implied by the use of a '#', '_' or other type annotation at or near  has been constrained to be type 'B'. Your second suggestion seems to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

F# does not always insert upcasts (conversion to a base type) automatically, so you have to insert an explicit cast that turns the `B` value into a value of type `A`.

Note that F# distinguishes between *upcasts* - casts to a base class (which are always correct) and *downcasts* - casts to a derived class (which may fail).

You can either use the `upcast` keyword or you can use the `expr :> Type` notation. In both cases, the compiler can fill in the required target type, so you can just write:

```
myList <- (upcast B())::myList
myList <- (B() :> _)::myList
```